# How to type hint a generic numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Is there any way to type a Numpy array as generic?

I'm currently working with Numpy 1.23.5 and Python 3.10, and I can't type hint the following example.

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt


E = TypeVar("E") # Should be bounded to a numpy type

def double_arr(arr: npt.NDArray[E]) -> npt.NDArray[E]:
    return arr * 2
```

What I expect

```py
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int8)
double_arr(arr) # npt.NDAarray[np.int8]

arr = np.array([1, 2.3, 3], dtype=np.float32)
double_arr(arr) # npt.NDAarray[np.float32]
```

But I end up with the following error

```py
arr: npt.NDArray[E]
                ^^^
Could not specialize type "NDArray[ScalarType@NDArray]"
  Type "E@double_arr" cannot be assigned to type "generic"
    "object*" is incompatible with "generic"
```

If i bound the E to numpy datatypes (`np.int8, np.uint8, ...`) the type-checker fails to evaluate the multiplication due to the multiple data-types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.5/numpy/_typing/_generic_alias.py#L238), it seems the generic type variable used to parameterize `numpy.dtype` of `numpy.typing.NDArray` is bounded by `numpy.generic` (and declared covariant). Thus any type argument to `NDArray` must be a subtype of `numpy.generic`, whereas your type variable is unbounded. This *should* work:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray


E = TypeVar("E", bound=np.generic, covariant=True)


def double_arr(arr: NDArray[E]) -> NDArray[E]:
    return arr * 2
```

But there is another problem, which I believe lies in insufficient numpy stubs. An example of it is showcased in [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22064). The overloaded operand (magic) methods like `__mul__` somehow mangle the types. I just gave [the code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.5/numpy/__init__.pyi#L2102) a cursory look right now, so I don't know what is missing. But `mypy` will still complain about the last line in that code:

```
error: Returning Any from function declared to return "ndarray[Any, dtype[E]]"  [no-any-return]
error: Unsupported operand types for * ("ndarray[Any, dtype[E]]" and "int")  [operator]
```

The workaround right now is to use the functions instead of the operands (via the dunder methods). In this case using [`numpy.multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) instead of `*` solves the issue:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray


E = TypeVar("E", bound=np.generic, covariant=True)


def double_arr(arr: NDArray[E]) -> NDArray[E]:
    return np.multiply(arr, 2)


a = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int8)
reveal_type(double_arr(a))
```

No more `mypy` complaints and the type is revealed as follows:

```py
numpy.ndarray[Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.signedinteger[numpy._typing._8Bit]]]
```

It's worth keeping an eye on that operand issue and maybe even report the specific error of `Unsupported operand types for *` separately. I haven't found that in the issue tracker yet.

---

**PS**: Alternatively, you could use the `*` operator and add a **specific** `type: ignore`. That way you'll notice, if/once the annotation error is eventually fixed by numpy because `mypy` complains about unused ignore-directives in strict mode.

```py
def double_arr(arr: NDArray[E]) -> NDArray[E]:
    return arr * 2  # type: ignore[operator,no-any-return]
```