Numpy type overloading
I'd like to add typehints to a function that accepts either np.float32 arrays or np.float64 arrays and returns the same type:
from typing import overload, Union

import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

NPArray_FLOAT32 = npt.NDArray[np.float32]
NPArray_FLOAT64 = npt.NDArray[np.float64]
NPArray_FLOAT32_64 = Union[NPArray_FLOAT32, NPArray_FLOAT64]

@overload
def foo(xa: NPArray_FLOAT32, xb: NPArray_FLOAT32) -> NPArray_FLOAT32: ...


@overload
def foo(xa: NPArray_FLOAT64, xb: NPArray_FLOAT64) -> NPArray_FLOAT64: ...


def foo(xa: NPArray_FLOAT32_64, xb: NPArray_FLOAT32_64) -> NPArray_FLOAT32_64:
    # ...


However, this results in the following error from mypy
mypy [overload-overlap]: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types.

What's the right way to do this? This almost seems like a bug with mypy since np.float32 does not overlap with np.float64.

I can't explain why Mypy doesn't accept your code as it is, but "the right way" here is to use a TypeVar: F = TypeVar('F', np.float32, np.float64) / def foo(xa: npt.NDArray[F], xb: npt.NDArray[F]) -> npt.NDArray[F]: ....

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633074/how-to-type-hint-a-generic-numpy-array

I think Mypy sees the two overloads as overlapping because Union[NPArray_FLOAT32, NPArray_FLOAT64] has both types and it can't definitively determine at the type-checking that the what the retun type should be

@Mo711 That's incorrect. The implementation's types are only used within its body.

The solution is to use TypeVar:
from typing import TypeVar, overload
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

T = TypeVar("T", np.float32, np.float64)


def add_32_64(xa: NDArray[T], xb: NDArray[T]) -> NDArray[T]:
    return xa + xb

# no issues when calling `add_32_64` with narrower types 
def add_64(xa: NDArray[np.float64], xb: NDArray[np.float64]) -> NDArray[np.float64]:
    return add_32_64(xa, xb)

Since it's exposing C++ functions from nanobind, this matches quite well with the function definitions since the functions are also defined in C++ with:
// NDArray defined earlier

template <typename T>
NDArray<T, 2>
foo(const NDArray<const T, 2> xa, const NDArray<const T, 2> xb) {

Credit
Resolved thanks to How to type hint a generic numpy array? (thanks Nick ODell) and insync. Thanks for your help!
